# Is it possible to transfer ownership back automatically?

Tags: rust, ownership, drop

If ownership from one struct is (partially) transferred to another struct (e.g. by copying part of its fields), how can it be "transferred back", as in how can I drop the former struct?

Consider this code:

```
struct User {
    active: bool,
    username: String
}

fn main() {
    let user1 = User { // create some user
        username: String::from("someusername123"),
        active: true,
    };

    let user2 = User { // create some other user. Copy some date from user1.
        active: false,
        ..user1 // Now ownership has been partially moved from user1 to user2
    };

    drop(user2); // we first drop user2. Now, ownership should be moved back to user1?
    drop(user1); // we want to delete user1. But ownership apparently hasn't been moved back. Error: use of partially moved value: `user1`
}
```

The last drop fails but it wouldn't if `user2` had not copied some field from `user1`.

It works well if `user2` copies `Copy`-able data from `user1`, like `bool`, because then only data in the stack gets copied to the best of my knowledge, but we get an issue if `user2` copies a `String` from `user1`.

Comment: That's not transferring ownership. That's making a new copy of the boolean in the second struct instance, because `bool` is a Copy type. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: If you do this with the `username: String` field instead, it does come up with some "partial move" errors. Is that what you're referring to?

Comment: I can compile and run your code without getting an error. What's the issue?

Comment: Ownership is about data and control. You can delegate control over data with a unique `&mut` reference, which will automatically return control when the owner of the `&mut` reference is dropped.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I meant to copy the String, as you suggested!

Comment: @PitaJ Thanks, I see... Is that possible with the `..user1` syntax? To make sure that contorl gets delegated back once user2 is dropped?

Comment: What you are describing, that you "temporarily move ownership to something else and then transfer it back once the object drops" is exactly what *borrowing* does. The wording isn't exactly correct, it's technically not a 'moving ownership', but for the most part, a mutable borrow behaves exactly like what you describe.

Comment: No, unfortunately that syntax can only be used with structs of the same type. You'll have to do each field manually. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d8c50a8e151dd3bfe4a7f9e9aa2337ce

Comment: I would say expecting `drop` to transfer ownership is exposing a huge misunderstanding of ownership. You can *only* drop something you explicitly own. You cannot drop something you do not own.

Answer (score 4):

Just to clarify, the `..user1` syntax is not copy or clone, but *move*. The ownership is transferred. With `bool` or other primitive types, they implement `Copy`, which is why when transferring ownership, they clone their data instead of being moved

In Rust, you cannot transfer the ownership of something and automatically have it move back. It is always the responsibility of the owner to move itself to somewhere else.

In your code example, when you initialize `user2`, the ownership of `username` is transferred, so `user1.username` is no longer accessible.  Thus from now on, **you no longer have access to the entire `user1`**, which is why you got the error `value used here after partial move` when trying to move its entirety to `drop()`. And it is now the responsibility of `user2` to move the `username` it owns back to `user1` before `user2` is dropped.

If you want to temporarily let `user2` have access to what `user1` holds, what you need is borrow.

```rust
struct User {
    active: bool,
    username: String
}

fn main() {
    let user1 = User {
        active: true,
        username: "someusername123".to_string(),
    };
    
    let user_ref = &user1;  // user_ref borrows user1, but user1 still owns the data
    
    drop(user_ref);     // Here only the borrow is dropped
    drop(user1);        // Here the data is moved into drop()  
}
```

If you also want to distinguish `user_ref` from `user1`, you can create a separate type that is a reference of `User` type

```rust
struct User {
    active: bool,
    username: String
}

struct UserRef<'a> {
    active: bool,
    username: &'a String,
}
impl User {
    fn as_user_ref<'a>(&'a self) -> UserRef<'a> {
        UserRef {
            active: false,
            username: &self.username,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let user1 = User {
        active: true,
        username: "someusername123".to_string(),
    };
    
    let user_ref = user1.as_user_ref();  // user_ref is type UserRef<'a>
    
    drop(user_ref);     // Here UserRef is dropped, but because it holds &String,
                        // nothing happens to the data
    
    drop(user1);        // Here the data is moved into drop()  
}
```

Or if what you want is just to copy user1, and the two variables are not related, just derive the `Clone` trait.

```rust
#[derive(Clone)]
struct User {
    active: bool,
    username: String
}
impl User {
    fn clone_inactive(&self) -> User {
        let mut user = self.clone();
        user.active = false;
        user
    }
}

fn main() {
    let user1 = User {
        active: true,
        username: "someusername123".to_string(),
    };
    
    let user2 = user1.clone_inactive(); // user1 is cloned, there are now 2 String
    
    drop(user2);     // The String owned by user2 is dropped
    drop(user1);     // The String owned by user1 is dropped
}
```